# How to delete first value in column at rest values convert to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have in SQL Server column "col1" where I have values like below:

```
col1
-----
1210607
1191011
1200101
```

I would like to convert this column to date column, by doing:

- 1210607 is 2021-06-07
- 1191011 is 2019-10-11
- 1200101 is 2020-01-01

So 1 is at the beginning of each row and it is useless, so I need to delete 1 at the beginning of each row and convert values to date format as above.

How can I do that in SQL Server?

Comment: What is the data type of `col1`?

Comment: 2 decades after Y2K - NO ONE should be using 2 digit years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the century -- 19000000 -- then convert to a string and a date:

```
select convert(date, convert(varchar(255), 19000000 + col1))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dec3420f8ed2416a6304db55cbbd2320) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Gordon, I have statement: where description like '%' || client || '%'  ----> Gordon, Is it possible to exclude anything from this list? for instanse befor or after "client" could be everything but not for instance "one" or "two" ?

Comment: @gato you need to ask a new question.